# const port = new SerialPort({ TypeError: SerialPort is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm struggling to make the serial port work. Can someone please help me I'm a beginner:)

I use npm version 10.2.5 and serialport version 12.0.0. I used also express 4.18.2 and ejs 3.1.9. All the latest versions I believe.

I'm just trying to make this code work but it complains that SerialPort is not a constructor. I tried downgrading serialport but it didnt help.

import SerialPort from "serialport";
const port = new SerialPort({ path: '/dev/ttyACM0', baudRate: 9600 });

I'm going to create a web app that can do a serial communication with Arduino Uno. Please advice :)

Thank you!

Emilija

I tried downgrading serialport but it didnt help.

Comment: I tried adding {} to the import: import { SerialPort } from "serialport"; and it helped! Then I added import Readline from '@serialport/parser-readline'; and const parser = portA.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '' })); and again it complains about the constructor! Adding curly brackets to Readline import didnt help

Comment: The module's name is `ReadlineParser`, not `Readline`. Please read documentation of the modules you want to use: https://serialport.io/docs/api-parser-readline.

Comment: If you still want to call it `Readline` you can of course do `import { ReadlineParser as Readline } from '@serialport/parser-readline'` and it will work as you expect it to

Comment: @slebetman thank you to much! The error is gone :)  I don't have access to Arduino today but will test it tomorrow.